# Related List is not showing up...?

Tags: custom-object, profile, page-layout, related-list, detail-page

I'm having an issue that a related list is not showing up on the detail page of the Asset object. When I try with the 'System Administrator' profile it shows up, but when I try with other profiles, it just won't show. As I have searched around the Internet, all I could find as a solution was to give 'READ' access to the related list object, but the issue persists even after I checked object and field level security. Please help!!!

Comment: Asset visibility is controlled by Parent so check Account

Comment: Where are trying? Classic or lightning? Is the issue persist for the both?

Comment: Just testing on classic only. Haven’t looked into lightning.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what was causing the issue!
As I was creating the related list object, I made the development status in 'In Development' instead of 'Deployed.' That is why only the 'System Administrator' was able to see the object showing on the related list.